# Powershell ForEach issue

Tags: powershell

Could someone explain whats wrong with this?

Thanks
Tom

```
$ProcessData = (Get-Counter '\Process(svchost*)\% Processor Time').Countersamples | Sort cookedvalue -Desc | Select-Object -First 1
ForEach($NamedProcess in $ProcessData)
{
echo $NamedProcess.ProcessId
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] should include errors, expected/deviating behaviour etc. [SO] is neither a script writing nor a debugging service.

Comment: It doesn't look like ProcessId is a property you'll get from the `Get-Counter` command, you have these properties to choose from:  `CookedValue,CounterType,DefaultScale,InstanceName,MultipleCount,Path,RawValue,SecondValue,Status,TimeBase,Timestamp,Timestamp100NSec
`

Comment: With `Select-Object -First 1` your `ForEach` loop does not really make any sense

Comment: As its multiple processes i want to order by highest cookedvalue and just used the first one, is there an easier way? Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments I've got rid of the unnecessary `ForEach` and changed `ProcessId` to `InstanceName` since there is no value for `ProcessId` available with the `Get-Counter` cmdlet.

```
$ProcessData = (Get-Counter '\Process(svchost*)\% Processor Time').Countersamples | Sort cookedvalue -Desc | Select-Object -First 1
$ProcessData.InstanceName
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks! clearly not thinking today, any idea how to get the PID of the process the Get-Counter is pulling? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to know `PID` for `InstanceName`, you can use below code:

```
$ProcessData = (Get-Counter '\Process(svchost*)\% Processor Time').Countersamples | Sort cookedvalue -Desc | Select-Object -First 1
Get-Process -Name $ProcessData.InstanceName | Select ID
```

Comment: Will this get the PID of the correct process if there are multiples running? Thanks

Comment: It lists out all PIDs of a particular process.

Comment: You may try this `Get-Process -Name $ProcessData.InstanceName | Sort-Object CPU -Descending | Select ID | Select -First 1`

Comment: If i run this it gives me a PID of one of the processes but not the correct one, is Sort-Object CPU correct? Thanks for your continued help on this

Comment: Ignore me! as I'm checking for svchost PowerShell needs to run as admin! thanks